# Calculate several timedifference give different output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table :

| entity_id | time_c | next_time_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '2023-01-02 10:34:36' | '2023-01-10 15:12:24' |
| 2 | '2023-03-01 16:10:12' | '2023-03-20 22:47:59' |

My goal is to calculate the interval between `time_c` and `next_time_c` without Saturday and Sunday and the full interval.

I come up with the following query :

```
WITH parms (entity_id, start_date, end_date) AS
(
    SELECT 
        entity_id,
        time_c::timestamp,
        next_time_c::timestamp
    FROM 
        test_c
), weekend_days (wkend) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(isodow FROM d) IN (6, 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    FROM 
        parms 
    CROSS JOIN 
        generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') dn(d)
)
SELECT 
    entity_id AS "ID",
    CONCAT(
        extract(day from diff), ' days ', 
        extract( hours from diff)   , ' hours ', 
        extract( minutes from diff) , ' minutes ', 
        extract( seconds from diff)::int , ' seconds '
    ) AS "Duration (excluding saturday and sunday)",
    justify_interval(end_date::timestamp - start_date::timestamp) AS "Duration full"
FROM (
    SELECT 
        start_date,
        end_date,
        entity_id,
        (end_date-start_date) - (wkend * interval '1 day') AS diff
    FROM parms 
    JOIN weekend_days ON true
) sq;
```

It works well when I have only 1 row in my table. When there is more than 1 row, the result is wrong.

With 1 row :

| ID | Duration (excluding saturday and sunday) | Duration full |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48 seconds | {"days":8,"hours":4,"minutes":37,"seconds":48} |

| ID | Duration (excluding saturday and sunday) | Duration full |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 13 days 6 hours 37 minutes 47 seconds | {"days":19,"hours":6,"minutes":37,"seconds":47} |

With 2 rows :

| ID | Duration (excluding saturday and sunday) | Duration full |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 days 4 hours 37 minutes 48 seconds | {"days":8,"hours":4,"minutes":37,"seconds":48} |
| 2 | 11 days 6 hours 37 minutes 47 seconds | {"days":19,"hours":6,"minutes":37,"seconds":47} |

Why the result is false when calculating several rows ?

Demo : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mDCS6cSwT1hbvit2WLYZbc/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate weekend days for each `entity_id` separately:

```sql
...
    SELECT 
        entity_id,
        SUM(case when extract(isodow from d) in (6, 7) then 1 else 0 end) 
    FROM 
        parms
    CROSS JOIN 
        generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') dn(d)
    GROUP BY entity_id
...
```

Check the full query in [Db-Fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pmsEDPsr5WPhKPsxH5uHMe/0)

---

Update. The above solution assumes that `entity_id` is unique as it is used to identify individual rows. If you do not have a unique column you can use a custom function or a lateral subquery. This is the second option:

```sql
select
    entity_id as "ID",
    concat(
        extract(day from diff), ' days ', 
        extract(hours from diff)   , ' hours ', 
        extract(minutes from diff) , ' minutes ', 
        extract(seconds from diff)::int , ' seconds '
    ) as "Duration (excluding saturday and sunday)",
    justify_interval(end_date - start_date) as "Duration full"
from (
    select 
        entity_id,
        time_c as start_date,
        next_time_c as end_date,
        (next_time_c - time_c) - weekend_days as diff
    from test_c,
    lateral (
        select sum((extract(isodow from d) in (6, 7))::int)* interval '1 day' as weekend_days
        from generate_series(time_c, next_time_c, '1 day') dn(d)
    ) wd
) sq;
```

Check it in [Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/jeQfsYuK)

Comment: Getting the wrong output if the entity_id are the same

Comment: Well, that's pretty obvious. You need a unique column to identify each row.

Comment: My data structure doesn't allow me to have a unique id